# nodejs - 'loadtest' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, autoscaling

I am trying to perform load test to increase the cpu utilization for server auto scaling feature.

I have installed `nodejs` and load test also through the [following site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest)

when I am trying to view 'loadtest' version, it is showing 'loadtest' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Even I have updated variable path also. But still i am facing this issue

Please help me to fix this issue.

Node version - v9.2.0
NPM version - 5.5.1
loadtest version - 3.0.4

[image: please find the attached ss for cmd screen]

Answer (score 1):

Global node modules are installed at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm`. Try adding that in your PATH env.

BTW, if you're using `npm` greater than 5.2, you can execute npm package directly with `npx`. Try `npx loadtest --version`.

My example below is that I didn't install `loadtest` globally so command not found, but I can type `npx loadtest` without install it globally.

[image]